# What is the following TV audio cable called?

Tags: audio, television, cable

[image]

I need your help to identify the following TV audio cable;

It's being connected to my LG TV monitor to the 'headphones' connector, it's shorter than aux cable (connecting aux cable to the headphones connector is falling out of the connector ('too long')).

How such a cable connector called, and where can I get it ? Am I missing something ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for audio splitter cables.  Then scroll until you find the matching plugs/sockets in type and dimensions.

It is not clear whether the single end is a socket or a plug.  This is close

[image]

Comment: This cable won't connect firmly and fall out, this end (like aux) doesn't work on my tv.

Comment: Your first cable is broken, the tip is missing…. if you can't get the one in this answer to fit in the socket properly, you've likely discovered what happened to the first tip - it's still in the socket.

Comment: @Tetsujin Checked what you said, and it's true indeed. Do you have a suggestion on how I can extract it out safely ?

Comment: Either the smallest pair of pliers or tweezers you can find, or hope & pray… a matchstick with superglue on the end.